# using vb.net to run ant release which will compile my android app

Tags: android, vb.net, ant

Currently I am attempting to run "ant release" from a vb.net project. I have tried using Process.start, I have tried using Shell. but unfortunately it seems that both of these either aren't executing ant or aren't giving it enough time to finish the build. If I run it in the command prompt it works fine.

Comment: Does it work if you run `cmd /C ant release` instead? Does redirecting STDOUT and STDERR (by adding `> output.txt 2>&1` to the command) give you any valuable clues?

Comment: No :( I think its because Ant was attempting to launch another program which actually signs the app. but I just did it manually instead which I am sure isn't the best way but it works